# Skipping the execute method of a job without aborting it

Tags: apex, batch

To provide a representative example, please consider the code below:

```
global class SampleJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    Boolean skipExecution;
    public SampleJob(Boolean skipExecution) {
        this.skipExecution = skipExecution;
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account';
        if(skipExecution) {
            return null;    
        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
        for (Account a : scope) {
            a.Phone='123';
        }
        update scope;
    }  
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('In finish');
    }
}
```

This is only a representative example, in reality my condition for skipping execute will depend on many runtime factors.

If I invoke this code with `Database.executeBatch(new SampleJob(false));`, my job should run as usual. However if I pass `true` as a parameter instead, I want the job to skip the `execute` method and execute `finish` directly. This, however gives me a

> System.UnexpectedException: Start did not return a valid iterable
>   object.

Is there any way to return a valid 0 size iterable so that the execute method can be skipped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the condition, instead of returning null, add `LIMIT 0` to the query.

Here is the updated start method:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account';
    if(skipExecution) {
        query += ' LIMIT 0';    
    }

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```